# How does Hibernate create a proxy object of final DTO class?

Tags: java, hibernate

If I make my DTO class as final, how does Hibernate create a proxy?

Code.

```
@Entity
public final class MyEntity {
    ...
}
```

I heard that Hibernate uses Reflection API to create a dynamic proxy of an object, and inherits it from a master class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It cannot create a proxy. From [the docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch04.html#persistent-classes-pojo-final):

> A central feature of Hibernate, proxies (lazy loading), depends upon
>   the persistent class being either non-final, or the implementation of
>   an interface that declares all public methods. You can persist final
>   classes that do not implement an interface with Hibernate; you will
>   not, however, be able to use proxies for lazy association fetching
>   which will ultimately limit your options for performance tuning. To
>   persist a final class which does not implement a "full" interface you
>   must disable proxy generation.